# Deprecated react-scripts dependencies

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, deprecation-warning, react-scripts

Recently started a react project using create-react-app. But when I did a clean install, I noticed the following warning messages:
[Deprecated dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp7x3.png)

These are all dependencies that I didn't install, so I checked my package-lock and these are all react-scripts dependencies.

Should I be concerned about this? Is there anything I can do to fix these deprecated dependencies? Apart from changing to another build tool like Vite. I considered ejecting the app, but that only allows me to fix one of the errors.

Any help is appreciated

I did a clean install by deleting my node_modules folder and using npm_install afterwards. Also tried ejecting the app but only allowed me to fix one of the deprecated dependencies . I was expecting no deprecated warnings

Comment: you can ignore those warnings

Comment: I suggest you add the error messages to your question in a code block, so people could copy them, if needed, and don't have to type them by hand from the image.